# Core Data does not overwrite object

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have an issue with Core Data. I have an entity called "Group", and other entity called "Contact". These entities have a relationship "many to many" between them, because a group could have many contacts (members of the group), and a contact could have many groups (be a member of many groups).

So, this is the relationship:

Group <<----->> Contact

What I need is insert contacts (new or existing) as members of existing groups.
What is my issue? Well...I am able to insert them if I create a new contact, but if the contact already exists, Core Data does not overwrite and save it.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)saveMemberInGroup:(Message *)message
{
    GroupInfo *groupInfo = message.group;
    UserInfo *member = message.user;

    AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [app managedObjectContext];
    NSError *error;

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:CONTACT_ENTITY
                                              inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ident == %@", [member ident]]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    //Here I check if the contact exists.
    Contact *contact;
    if ([fetchedObjects count] == 0) {
        contact = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:CONTACT_ENTITY
                                                inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [contact setIdent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [member ident]]];
    } else {
        contact = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    //Now I make a new request for the group.
    fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:GROUP_ENTITY
                         inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ident == %@", [groupInfo ident]]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    Group *group = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];

    //Now, I overwrite the group and the contact.
    [[group members]addObject:contact];
    [[contact memberGroups]addObject:group];

    [context save:&error];
}
```

Here is my Group entity:

```
@interface Group : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *ident;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableSet *members;

@end
```

And my Contact entity:

```
@interface Contact : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *ident;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableSet *memberGroups;

@end
```

**NOTE:**

This is really weird...when I check if I have updated the objects successfully, everything seems to be ok, both groups and contacts have their NSSet updated rightly, but when I restart the app (I mean, finalize and start it again, or press "play" in XCode), Core Data only has saved the relationship with the new contacts created!!.

Example:

1. Create Contact1 and save in Group1.
2. Create Contact2 and save in Group1.
3. Existing Contact1 and save in Group2.
4. Create Contact3 and save in Group2.

If I check Core Data when my app is running, I will have in Group1 (Contact1, Contact2), and in Group2 (Contact1, Contact3).

Then I restart the app and check again Core Data, and now I have in Group1 (Contact1, Contact2), and in **Group2 (Contact3)**!! Core Data has lost the relationship between Contact1 and Group2, and this happens every time I have a relationship between a group and an existing contact.

What I am doing wrong??

Thanks a lot!.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create the class files for your entities with "Editor -> Create NSManagedObject
Subclasses ..." from the Xcode menu. A to-many relationship is represented by an `NSSet`,
not a `NSMutableSet`, so you cannot modify it directly by adding an object.

Once you have done that, you can add an additional object to `group.members` with

```
[group addMembersObject:contact];
```

or alternatively

```
[contact addMemberGroupsObject:group];
```

Core Data updates inverse relationships automatically, so it does not matter
which one you choose.

Comment: I would recommend the mogenerator tool to create your classes rather than Xcode. http://rentzsch.github.io/mogenerator/

Comment: Be careful with this autogenerated methods like `[group addMembersObject:contact];` .In previous versions, they have to be overriden.

Comment: @MikePollard: It is probably a matter of taste whether to use Xcode or mogenerator (I still use Xcode), but it is good that you mention it as an alternative.

Comment: @Foriger: They have to be overridden for *ordered* relationships, is that what you are referring to?

Comment: Thanks!! I have changed my class files for my entities, and everything works nice. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MartinR Does xcode generate two classes per entity these days so that you can customise one without losing your changes if you regenerate? That is the main benefit of mogenerator for me.

Comment: @MikePollard: You are definitely right that mogenerator is useful if you have to customize the classes. As long as you don't need additional properties, you can achieve the same with categories. - But *if* you need additional properties or instance variables then mogenerator is probably the method that is easiest to maintain.

Comment: @MikePollard You are right.That's for ordered relationships.